# Spectrogram - Am I missing something?

Tags: fft, python, spectrogram, stft

I have the following signal:

[image]

I'm trying to compute a Spectrogram algorithm, but, don't think I'm doing it right..

I have computed the following:

1) STFT (size 256 with an overlap of 128) 
 2) Computed the logs using: '10 * log10(sqrt(re * re + im + im)

This is the result that I get:

[image]

But when I use `pylab` in Python (for the same signal):
  `x = pl.specgram(signal)`

I get the following result:

[image]

Using the `matplotlib` I get the following:

[image]

Obviously, these are very different results.. I don't know why I'm getting these, I'm new to signal processing and spectrograms. Hope someone can help

EDIT:

This is the result I have when doing `imshow` in python:

[image]

Comment: How can you can call figure no. 2 a spectrogram when there is a time and amplitude on axis? To me it looks like a squared signal in log scale. I have the feeling that you first should read about: [STFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STFT). You must split your signals into frames, calculate DFT for each of them (this will give you a spectrum) and in the result you will obtain a matrix - MxN (M - number of frames, N - number of frequency bins). From that point you can play further. Some basic reference for python: [scipy STFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459295/stft-and-istft-in-python)

Comment: "Using the matplotlib I get the following:"  You're plotting a 2-dimensional array, so it interprets it as multiple 1-dimensional plots.  You need to use imshow or pcolor or something.  What is the `arrayname.shape` of your array?  Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be just a matter of projection. Try "imagesc" in matlab.

Comment: Please see my updated post. Why am I getting such a result? :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems you obtain one value for each time considered.
You should be taking the fourier transform of the signal with a window centered on the point t1, this gives you a spectrum (a vector, not a scalar), move to t2, repeat that gives a second spectrum and so on.
Spectrogram will be a collection of spectra indexed by time, it is a time/frequency representation, your result is 1D not 2D